# Css attribute not changing (javascript)

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a piece of code that will change the content of my webpage by clicking on links. It hides the div displayed now and replaces it with another one.

The html is this:

```
        <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#" id="Overview_button"  >  Overview                          </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="javascript:changeContent('Backgrounds');">                                Backgrounds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Boxes_button">   Boxes</a>                          </li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="Colors" >   Colors</a>                          </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" id="Navigation_button">                                Navigation</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#" id="Positining_button">                                Positioning</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#" id="Text_button">  Text</a>                                </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">                               Conclusion </a></li>
                </ul>
```

Right now the function is only applied to the second element since thats the one I am testing with. The id 'Backgrounds' refers to a div later in the text.

The javascript is:

```
var currentContent = 'Overview';

function changeContent(newContent) {
document.getElementById(currentContent).style.display = "none";
document.getElementByID(newContent).style.display = "block";
currentContent = newContent;
};
```

It succesfully hides the old content, but does not show the new.

Answer (score 2):

> document.getElementByID

Should be

```
document.getElementById
```

Anyway, you should check errors in your console before posting such questions.

Comment: what do you mean in my console? sorry I am coding this all in wordpad as part of a challenge and am completely new to javascript otherwise... how do i check things in console?

Comment: You are running this in a browser. All modern browsers have Developer Tools with a Javascript Console in them that will show you when javascript on the page is throwing errors.

Comment: F12 in all modern desktop browsers, except Ctrl+Alt+C in Safary